# Missing argument 1 for IndexController in search query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

So im trying to make a query with multiple parameters coming out from a form to perform a property search method. But I am struggling with my `showResults` method as i continuously get `Missing argument 1 for IndexController::showResults()`. Also i want to make sure how to search through my many to many relation between properties and categories. `categories[]` is a select multiple in my form.

This is my code so far.

```
Route::get('buscar/propiedades', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'IndexController@showResults'));
Route::post('buscar/propiedades', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'IndexController@searchProperties'));

public function showResults($categories, $activity, $currency, $beds, $baths, $price)
{
    return View::make('front.results')
                ->with('properties', Property::join('category_property', 'properties.id', '=', 'category_property.property_id')
                    ->join('categories', 'category_property.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->join('activities', 'activities.id', '=', 'properties.activity_id')
                    ->join('currencies', 'currencies.id', '=', 'properties.currency_id')
                    ->whereIn('categories.id', $categories)
                    ->orWhere('activities.id', '=', $activity)
                    ->orWhere('currencies.id', '=', $currency)
                    ->orWhere('properties.beds', '=', $beds)
                    ->orWhere('properties.baths', '=', $baths)
                    ->orWhere('properties.price', '=', $price)
                    ->paginate(6);
}

public function searchProperties()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Property::$search_rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withInput(); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    }else{
        $categories = Input::get('category_id');
        $activity = Input::get('activity_id');
        $currency = Input::get('currency_id');
        $beds = Input::get('beds');
        $baths = Input::get('baths');
        $price = Input::get('price');
    }

    $this->showResults($categories, $activity, $currency, $beds, $baths, $price);

    return Redirect::to('buscar/propiedades');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation must be failing meaning the variables that you pass as params are not defined.

Try to call your method after you set your vars, or set your vars and call your method.

Try:

```
public function searchProperties()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Property::$search_rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withInput(); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    }else{
        $categories = Input::get('category_id');
        $activity = Input::get('activity_id');
        $currency = Input::get('currency_id');
        $beds = Input::get('beds');
        $baths = Input::get('baths');
        $price = Input::get('price');

        $this->showResults($categories, $activity, $currency, $beds, $baths, $price);
    }

    return Redirect::to('buscar/propiedades');
}
```

In pseudocode this will:

1. Create a validator with the input and your rules array
2. If it fails, redirects to the root route with no input
3. If it passes, it will set all of your variables equal to the input, and call the    `showResults` method with those variables as params.

And finally redirect to your URI.

Comment: All variables are coming out correctly. The problem is in the query i guess. $categories is an array and i dont know if its causing the error

Comment: If it's not selecting the right data we'll need to see your schema/model so we can understand why.

Comment: I have edited my code and i still get Missing argument 1 for IndexController::showResults()

Comment: Is there a route that's tied to this method and does it have a route param?

Comment: Route::get('buscar/propiedades', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'IndexController@showResults'));
Route::post('buscar/propiedades', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'IndexController@searchProperties'));

Comment: You can't have both named search.